# Airflow not recognising zip file DAG built with pytest fixture

Tags: python, zip, airflow, google-cloud-composer

We are using Google Composer (a managed Airflow service) with airflow v1.10 and Python 3.6.8. 
To deploy our DAGS, we are taking the Packaged DAG (https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=zip#packaged-dags) method.

All is well when the zip file is created from the cmd line like

```
zip -r dag_under_test.zip test_dag.py
```

but when I try to do this from a pytest fixture, so I load in the DagBag and test the integrity of my DAG, airflow doesnt recognise this zip file at all. here is the code to my pytest fixture

```
@fixture
def setup(config):
    os.system("zip -r dag_under_test.zip test_zip.py")


def test_import_dags(setup):
    dagbag = DagBag(include_examples=False)
    noOfDags = len(dagbag.dags)
    dagbag.process_file("dag_under_test.zip")
    assert len(dagbag.dags) == noOfDags + 1, 'DAG import failures. Errors: {}'.format(dagbag.import_errors)
```

I copied this zip file to the DAGs folder, but airflow isnt recognising it at all, no error messages.
But the zip file built with same command from cmdline is being loaded by airflow!! seems like I am missing something obvious here, cant figure out.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it looks like there is a mismatch between the working directory of `os.system` and where the DagBag loader is looking. If you inspect the code of [`airflow/dagbag.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/dagbag.py), the path accepted by `process_file` is passed to `os.path.isfile`:

```py
def process_file(self, filepath, only_if_updated=True, safe_mode=True):
  if filepath is None or not os.path.isfile(filepath):
    ...
```

That means within your test, you can probably do some testing to make sure all of these match:

```py
# Make sure this works
os.path.isfile(filepath)

# Make sure these are equal
os.system('pwd')
os.getcwd()
```

Comment: I tried them, but it didnt make any difference. The path I am creating the test is valid (os.path.isfile)

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that where I am creating the zip file is important. As in this case I am creating the zip file from the test folder and archiving the files in src folders. Although the final zip file looks perfect for the naked eye, airflow is rejecting it. 
I tried with adding '-j' to the zip command (to junk the directory names) and my test started working.

`zip -r -j dag_under_test_metrics.zip ../src/metricsDAG.py`

I had another bigger problem, i.e. to test the same scenario when there is a full folder structure in my DAG project. A dag file at the top level which references a lots of python modules with in the project. I couldnt get this working by the above trick, but came up with a workaround. I have created a small shell script, which does the zip part, like this..

```
SCRIPT_PATH=${0%/*/*}
cd $SCRIPT_PATH

zip -r -q test/dag_under_test.zip DagRunner.py
zip -r -q test/dag_under_test.zip tasks dag common resources
```

This shell script is changing the currentdir to project home and archiving from there. I am invoking this shell from the pytest fixture like this

```
@fixture
def setup():
    os.system('rm {}'.format(DAG_UNDER_TEST))
    os.system('sh {}'.format(PACKAGE_SCRIPT))
    yield
    print("-------- clean up -----------")
    os.system('rm {}'.format(DAG_UNDER_TEST))
```

This is perfectly working with my integration test.

```
def test_conversionDAG(setup):
    configuration.load_test_config()
    dagbag = DagBag(include_examples=False)
    noOfDags = len(dagbag.dags)
    dagbag.process_file(DAG_UNDER_TEST)
    assert len(dagbag.dags) == noOfDags + 1, 'DAG import failures. Errors: {}'.format(dagbag.import_errors)
    assert dagbag.get_dag("name of the dag")
```